# What are the origins of using the abbreviation "v." for "very"?

Tags: british-english, slang

Looking to figure out where the abbreviation "v." originates from.

I know "v." was heavily used in "Bridget Jones Diary," but that movie came out over a decade ago and was British.

- What are the origins?
- Why are Americans suddenly adopting this usage?

Comment: I'm a native AmE speaker, any the only times I ever see "v." used is where space is at a premium: Twitter, txts, titles of Ebay or other online auctions, etc. I've also seen it sometimes, less frequently, used to reduce typing effort (as in quick IMs); in those cases, the period is elided. The only time I've seen it used in a formal context is by speakers of Indian English (where it comes across as stilted, self-conscious, and a little silly to my American ears).

Comment: Movie? Bridget Jones Diary was a novel (2 million copies worldwide in its first 10 years), and a popular column in a national newspaper before that. I suspect those had more influence on written English than the movie.

Comment: According to:http://www.internetslang.com/V-meaning-definition.asp,  it is part of Internet slang. As such it should be used with care:)

Comment: @Josh61, "*v.*" has been in use long before the advent of the internet. It was used in the heydey of Victorian letter-writing (no one likes hand-cramps), later in the telegraph and telegram systems (where you paid by the length of the missive), in numismatic grading (*fine*, *v. fine*, *mint*), and so on.  There's nothing particularly special about this particular abbreviation, except that it is commoner than most given that it's a word used with some frequency, and its context and unusual initial letter allow it to be used in situations with a very low risk of ambiguity or unclarity.

Comment: The advent of the Internet and texting could be an answer to the second question.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, I believe so, see my first comment (but note the caveats on prior usage in my second comment).

Comment: V. simple. _Very_ starts with _v_, and there aren't v. many words that do. Practically none that can be used right before a variable adjective.

Comment: @JohnLawler unfortunately, one of those few words is "versus" which is already abbreviated to v. as in "Roe v. Wade". So I guess we could abbreviate "'versus' versus 'very'" as "v.v.v."

Comment: _Versus_ is _`X` v. `Y`_, but _very_ is _v. `X`_, a different pattern. Just like _he's_ is _he has_ before a past participle but _he is_ before a present participle.

Comment: Versus is often abbreviated as vs.

Comment: @Oldcat Indeed it is. I think _v._ is mostly confined to the legal use, where its very commonness prevents any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The OED has it dating back to 1863 in *The Quarterly Review*:

> It is said also, that the prisoners have been known to make an example of a warden who was not in their opinion sufficiently liberal with his V.G.'s (‘Very Good,’ as marked in the accounts).